# how to prevent windows server 2016 share from holding file locks after a disconnects?

Tags: windows-server-2016, file-sharing

I have a Windows Server 2016 server with a file share that clients have write permissions to.  Sometimes clients disconnect while the client has file locks that are not released.

Here is a view using 'openfiles.exe' of the share with the file.txt locked.

```
openfiles.exe //Query //s servername //v
servername 56784213 user                 Windows    0          Read            D:\share\subfolder
servername 95678421 [Disconnected]       Windows    0          Write + Read    D:\share\subfolder\a\file.txt
```

The problem is when this client comes back online (same system, same IP address) and it tries to read or write file.txt, it gets a permission denied error.

I have seen similar issues reported on Samba, [How to prevent samba from holding a file lock after a client disconnects?](https://serverfault.com/questions/204812/how-to-prevent-samba-from-holding-a-file-lock-after-a-client-disconnects).
Also, on old Windows Server versions (I used to run Server 2008 many years ago), this was not a problem.

I would like to know how to control what Windows does when the same client disconnects with file locks open and then re-connects.  I would like it to kill previous connections from the same client/same IP.

Comment: any timeout listed there changed ? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2013/03/19/cifs-and-smb-timeouts-in-windows/